# In which sense an expansive matrix is expansive

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. $A$ is called **an expansive matrix** if every eigenvalue of $A$ is strictly bigger than 1.

From the name "expansive", one may deduce that (the space of square expansive matrices will be denoted as $E_n(\mathbb{R})$): $$\forall A\in E_n(\mathbb{R}),\exists c>1: \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n, |||Ax|||\ge c|||x|||$$ where $|||\cdot|||$ is some norm which depends on the choice of $A$.

However, I cannot see why this statement is correct. I tried something like $$|||x|||=\lim_{n\to\infty} (\Vert Ax\Vert ^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ but it doesn't satisfy the inequality (e.g. for $A=I_n$ the identity matrix).  How can I choose that norm s.t. it'll satisfy this inequality?

Comment: In your definition of 'expansive', $c$ only shows up once. Did you mean $|||Ax||| \geq c|||x|||$?

Comment: Presumably you mean $|||Ax||| \geq c |||x|||$. If that is what you meant, there are a few ways to see this. In the diagonalizable case you can more or less read it off from the diagonalization expansion and the triangle inequality. In the nondiagonalizable case, you can invert, find an induced norm which is nearly equal to the spectral radius, and then invert back. Alternately you can work more directly with the Jordan normal form.

Comment: @lan on the first case: How I can apply here the triangle inequality? On the other case: So the induced norm here is $$\Vert x\Vert=\rho(A^{-1})x$$?

Comment: Write out $Ax=\sum c_i \lambda_i y_i$, then estimate the $\lambda_i$ from below by the smallest eigenvalue. For the other case, I actually mean the *matrix* norm. The problem is that the spectral radius is not a matrix norm (in fact it is not a norm at all). But it is "almost" a matrix norm, in the sense that there is a norm which is arbitrarily close to it.

Comment: This norm is $||| x|||=\Vert (Ax)^{-k}\Vert^{\frac 1 k} $?

Comment: You keep writing it as a vector norm, it's not a vector norm. For any matrix $A$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a vector norm $\| \cdot \|$ which induces a matrix norm $| \| \cdot \| |$ such that $| \| A \| | \leq \rho(A)+\varepsilon$.

Comment: Why it's correct? Can you precisly give me $|||\cdot|||$?

Comment: I cannot present it explicitly. The idea is that, using the Jordan normal form, $A^k x = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i n_i^k \lambda_i^k y_i$, where $c_i$ are coefficients depending on $x$, $n_i$ are positive integers, $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues, and $y_i$ are eigenvectors or generalized eigenvectors. In the diagonalizable case, all the $n_i$ are $1$ and all the $y_i$ are truly eigenvectors.

Comment: Then the idea is the same as the idea behind the ratio test: $n_i^k \lambda_i^k$ grows faster asymptotically than $\lambda_i^k$ but slower than $(\lambda_i+\varepsilon)^k$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.